# How to code in perl using subroutines

Tags: perl

I need to score my string patches following certain criteria:

Column 1: B for buried or E for Exposed - Threshold: 25%
Column 2: Amino acid
Column 3: Sequence name
Column 4: Amino acid number
Column 5: Relative Surface Accessibility - RSA
Column 6: Absolute Surface Accessibility
Column 7: Z-fit score for RSA prediction
Column 8: Probability for Alpha-Helix
Column 9: Probability for Beta-strand
Column 10: Probability for Coil

```
E K  132L_A_PDBID_CHAIN_SEQUENCE     1    0.716 147.261   1.150   0.016   0.005   0.979  
E V  132L_A_PDBID_CHAIN_SEQUENCE     2    0.514  79.033   1.252   0.191   0.086   0.723  
B F  132L_A_PDBID_CHAIN_SEQUENCE     3    0.134  26.793  -0.325   0.191   0.086   0.723  
E G  132L_A_PDBID_CHAIN_SEQUENCE     4    0.570  44.835   1.012   0.354   0.048   0.598
```

Remember, the last three columns are the probabilities for either Helix/Sheet/Coil.......

So first we need to classify whether a certain residue falls under Helix/Sheet/Coil using some criterion function....based on the max. probability within the last 3 columns...

Then one we get the structural preferences, we need to score the sequences breaking into patches of 10......

My scoring criteria is this:

```
EXPOSED     = 1; # +1 for letters that exposed  
BURIED      = 0; #  0 for letters that are buried  
COIL        = 3; # +3 for any coil  
HELIX       = 2; # +2 for any helix  
SHEET       = 1; # +1 for any sheet
```

The link below is for breaking a string into patches of 10~11

http://pastebin.com/GeW5AKF3

The problem I am facing is that I have splitted in string into horizontal patches as in the above link, but the file is vertically aligned......

Thanks for help....... Waiting for reply

Comment: What have you tried so far and what did it do or not do? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please show the code you have written and explain what the problem is with that code.

Comment: The link is mentioned above

Comment: Stackoverflow questions should be self-contained. Links to other sites where the information may disappear will be useless in the future. The Pastebin FAQ says "Pastebin.com is a website where you can store text for a certain period of time" suggesting that the entries will have a limited lifetime. Please re-read my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
open my $fh, "<", "input.txt";

my @data;
while(my $line = <$fh>) # If we got line from file
{
    chomp $line; # remove carraigereturn/linefeed
    my @parts = split /\s+/, $line; # split based on values seperated by one or more spaces
    push @data, [@parts] # Add array of split parts to data array
}
```

Thats puts everything into @data. You access it like this:

```
# now access whatever you want...
# example: line 3 column 6 (perl arrays start from 0 not 1):
print $data[2][5] . "\n"; #prints 26.793

# line 4 column 2:
print $data[3][1] . "\n"; #prints G
```

Then you can sort like this. (Example sort by Col1 then by Col5(RSA):)

```
    @data = sort { if ( $a->[0] eq $b->[0] ) { $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] } else { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } } @data;
```

Then output data like this:

```
foreach my $line (@data)
{   
    foreach my $field (@$line)
    {
        print $field."\t";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Output is:

```
B   F   132L_A_PDBID_CHAIN_SEQUENCE 3   0.134   26.793  -0.325  0.191   0.086   0.723   
E   V   132L_A_PDBID_CHAIN_SEQUENCE 2   0.514   79.033  1.252   0.191   0.086   0.723   
E   G   132L_A_PDBID_CHAIN_SEQUENCE 4   0.570   44.835  1.012   0.354   0.048   0.598   
E   K   132L_A_PDBID_CHAIN_SEQUENCE 1   0.716   147.261 1.150   0.016   0.005   0.979
```